# LoadI command is not recognized in MARIE simulator

Tags: memory-access, marie

I downloaded the MARIE simulator from a site that is no longer available and wrote a small program which just declares an array of hexadecimal numbers and then attempts to retrieve one of those numbers using the address.

The problem is that the assembler complains that `loadi` is not a recognized instruction. If I use `load` rather than `loadi`, it will assemble and run and print the expected output (the address of the value I want).

I believe `loadi` should work and is the instruction I need because of my previous understanding of it which is that it will load the value found at the address given by the operand, as well as some documentation I found on sites like [this one](https://github.com/MARIE-js/MARIE.js/wiki/MARIE-Instruction-Set-(with-Opcodes)) and [this one](http://hwmath.com/dev/MarieSim/Marie-Instruction-Set-Cheat-Sheet.pdf).

Why is `loadi` not recognized? Am I doing something wrong? Maybe there are different versions of MARIE with varying support for some of the instructions?

My MARIE code:

```
ORG 0

    JUMP    start
BADDR,  hex 0003    / Date_B = 0003
EADDR,  hex 001A    / Date_E = 001A
    / data section begins
Data_B, hex 0102 / data begin address    3
    hex 0105 / dec 261
    hex 0106 / dec 262
    hex 0108 / dec 264
    hex 011A / dec 282
    hex 0120 / dec 288
    hex 0225 / dec 549
    hex 0230 / dec 560      10
    hex 0231 / dec 561
    hex 0238 / dec 568
    hex 0339 / dec 825
    hex 0350 / dec 848
    hex 0459 / dec 1113     000F
    hex 055F / dec 1375
    hex 066A / dec 1642
    hex 0790
    hex 08AB
    hex 09AF
    hex 0AB9
    hex 0BBD
    hex 0CC1
    hex 0DCA               
    hex 0EFE /                 0019
Data_E, hex 0FFE / data end address 001A
Count,  dec 24          / the number of data

start,  loadi mid
        output
        halt

mid,      hex   000F / starting mid point
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact that the particular version of MARIE I was using did not support the instruction. I downloaded the MARIE simulator from a [different site](http://www.jblearning.com/catalog/9781284123036/) and it works great. Problem solved.